# Asp.Net bundling Issue after hosting website on different server

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle

I am using asp.net bundling. My code is

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundle)
{
    var commonStylesBundle = new CustomStyleBundle("~/Users/bundles/css");
    commonStylesBundle.Include(
         "~/Users/css/reset.css",
        "~/Users/css/fullcalendar.css",
        "~/Users/css/datatable.css",
        "~/Users/css/prettyPhoto.css",
        "~/Users/css/elfinder.css",
       "~/Users/css/main.css",
       "~/Users/css/tiny-carousel.css",
       //"~/Users/css/spinners.css",
        "~/Users/js/plugins/bootstrap-tour-0.9.1/css/bootstrap-tour-standalone.css",
        //"~/css/css-d.css",
        "~/Users/css/developer_uicustom.css",
         "~/Users/js/plugins/Jquery-datetimepicker/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css",
        "~/css/smart_wizard.css",
        "~/Users/js/plugins/qTip/jquery.qtip.min.css"
    );

    //commonStylesBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
    bundle.Add(commonStylesBundle);   
}
```

and on the aspx page I wrote this line

```
 <%: Styles.Render("~/Users/bundles/css") %>
```

and in the `web.config` file I set debug compilation to `false`:

```
 <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" batch="false" 
              optimizeCompilations="true">
```

It's working fine on local host but when I move this work on hosting server it says 404 file not found. I am not able to track any error. How can I solve this issue on hosting server, so that bundling starts working again?

Comment: Which is the offending URL? How did you do the deployment?

Comment: website is hosted on IIS and the address of he website like this.
https://ip/user/abc.aspx

Comment: website is hosted on IIS and the address of he website like this.

Comment: @HaseebKhan, He meant to ask which URL exactly is causing the 404 error?

Comment: https://localhost:port number/Users/bundles/css?v=IXO38wWndA7I0b96hLENVcU6yOJPueNoKLqH9K1PrL41

this is the local host url which works fine. But on the hosted server the url becomes like this and it wont work 
https://ip/Users/bundles/css?v=IXO38wWndA7I0b96hLENVcU6yOJPueNoKLqH9K1PrL41